# Could not open "Pentaho User Console" page in browser

Tags: pentaho, kettle, javapos

I'm working on Java Pos and I'm a newbie. I need (kettle) Pentaho Data Integration in order to integrate the Java POS' database with the database in the ERP. I followed the following manual 
"http://www.scribd.com/doc/19583351/Install-Guide-for-Pentaho-Business-Intelligence-BI-Suite-CE"
and I'm stuck at Part 3- Step 1. When I type localhost address in the browser, instead of getting pentaho login page i'm getting a "HTTP Status 404" error. 
Do I've to change the tomcat server port or anything else? Please, help me find out the glitch in this program?

Answer (score 1):

Check your server.xml to see what port is listening on. I assume when you started tomcat it started successfully? ( check the log for errors )

Use google.

Finally, if you want to use ETL/Kettle then you need to start off looking at the Spoon tool - this is the UI for building ETL.  So look at that first perhaps.

(you dotn even need the BI server if all you're doing is ETL.)